# How to specify a run timeout with VSTest.Console?

Tags: vstest

With MSTest.exe, you can specify a total timeout for a test run by setting the `/TestSettings/Execution/Timeouts/@runTimeout` attribute in a .testsettings file.

With VSTest.Console.exe, the .testsettings has been deprecated in favor of .runsettings, which apparently has a completely different schema (with, ahem, sparse documentation).  I know that I can configure the .runsettings file to use legacy MSTest mode (thereby allowing me to use a .testsettings file), but I would prefer to avoid that if possible.

Is there a way to set a run timeout in the .runsettings file?  Or is there a different way to get the same effect?

Comment: I tried adding the `<Timeouts testTimeout="30000" />` at every possible location in the `.runsettings` file to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. Please see RFC here: [0011-Test-Session-Timeout.md](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/RFCs/0011-Test-Session-Timeout.md)

Comment: TestSessionTimeout is helpful for defining a timeout for the total runtime of all tests in a session.  But even more helpful would be the ability to set a timeout for individual tests to prevent long running tests.  I haven't found that.  My module might have 31 tests that all take one second, where I don't necessarily want that session to fail after 30 seconds.  However, if I have one bad test that runs for 31+ seconds, I'd like that to fail.